# Floating Action Button - Rendering issue at design and runtime

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, floating-action-button, androiddesignsupport

Have observation while working with a simple design for Login Screen with two EditText and a Floating Action Button.

> **Observation:** Views rendered incorrectly; take a look at below XML code for layout and the attached image showing design-time view for layout.

> **NOTE:** Same UI appears on real or virtual devices too.

**activity_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.LoginActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dip"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etUsername"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mobile"
            android:drawablePadding="10dip"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/username"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
            tools:ignore="Autofill" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_key"
            android:drawablePadding="10dip"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
            tools:ignore="Autofill" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/screen_size"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="@string/forget_password"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**style.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**This is how it looks like.**
[image]

Other things that might require for more!

- Android Studio: 4.0
- compileSdkVersion 30
- buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"
- minSdkVersion 21
- argetSdkVersion 30

below is the list of dependencies used

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
}
```

Comment: how you want to render Floating Action Button?

Comment: The material components library requires a Material components theme

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the floating Action Button is that you haven't set the

`android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"` which is **required** to set the button to the bottom position of the layout.
Also add `android:layout_margin="value"` to determine its relative postion from the layout borders.

Comment: Why is it require? It can be placed everywhere.

Comment: yes, you are right, It can be placed anywhere but the what appears as the person asking this question isn't satisfied with the position of the floating action button. Maybe he wanted it to be its usual place, at the bottom.

Comment: @AnuragDhadse I'm not looking to correct the position of FAB; Please read my observation and Note mentioned above to better understand the scenario. Thanks for the help!